# accent insensitive search in SOQL

Tags: soql

I am trying to do some accent insensitive search in SOQL. Using things like:

> **SELECT name WHERE name LIKE '%andre%'**

I would like the database to return me a list of names like **Alexandre**, **Andre** or **André**. I already checked SalesForce link: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fsforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm|SkinName=webhelp discussing about the different comparison operators but without success. Has anyone already been confronted to that type of problem in SOQL, and found an answer to it?

Thank you.

Comment: You should probably post this on the [Salesforce side of StackExchange](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I posted the question on Salesforce side of StackExchange. Thanks Andrew.